# Move the value of all cells in a column to their corresponding excel row number

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say i have the below list of Whole numbers in Column A. If you observe the list of numbers, you will see that number "5" and 6 is missing.

```
A
3
2
4
1
7
8
```

what I want to achieve is to place (sort) the numbers on the column such that each cell value will take its position according to excel row numbering. which means:

I should have something like this

```
1
2
3
4


7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's as simple as stated, this should work.

In column B, say:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,ROW())>0,ROW(),"")
```

[image]

Note: It does not account for duplicates, or anything complicated really.

Further Note: To clarify, all this does is check if the row that the formula is in, is in column A.  If it is, then it returns the current row.

Comment: Who thought you?

Worked like African marjik.

Thanks a bunch @BruceWayne

Comment: @AdoDixn you can tick the check mark left of the answer to mark this as The Answer, fyi. Glad it worked!